# Where can I find the Apache Flex (Version 4.9) documentation?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I was looking for the latest Apache Flex documentation, like the asdoc.
Where can I find it? and how can I integrate it into Flash Builder?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache Flex docs aren't live yet, but you can find them at http://flex.apache.org/v2/asdoc/.

Note the "v2" in that path: it means this will be the next version of the Apache Flex site, but isn't officially active yet. As such you can expect to find some shortcomings in the docs. One that I know of is that there are no links to Adobe's ActionScript classes, like - say - `flash.display.Sprite`.

I'm afraid I can't help you much with the FlashBuilder integration though, but the docs are usually included in the SDK. If I remember correctly (my FB days are some time behind me) you can add the path to the docs in the "build path" config screen.

Comment: Flash Builder also gets the context help from "fat" secs, these secs have extra XML information in them describing their methods, properties and classes. These are built for Apache Flex 4.9 so just getting Flash Builder to use the new SDK should be enough.